# NFC credit card

Tags: nfc, google-wallet

I'm wondering, if I can use my NFC phone as a credit card... how can I solve it? As I think, Google Wallet has this feature, but I'm not from US, I can't install it from Play.

Do someone know some other way, how to do this?

Releated, but not the same question: [Do the new NFC options in 4.4 Kitkat allow one to have a combined digital wallet?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/57078/do-the-new-nfc-options-in-4-4-kitkat-allow-one-to-have-a-combined-digital-wallet/57080)

Comment: What country are you in? Your country may have similar platforms that support this. But without such an application, you have no ability to do it on your own.

Comment: I'm from Hungary, Central Europe.

Comment: I'm having trouble confirming its availability, but it seems like this may be to your interest: http://www.mobiltarca.com/en

Comment: Thanks, but it seems that it is just for T-mobile postpaid customers - what a shame... ( http://www.t-mobile.hu/lakossagi/tarifak/szolgaltatasok/mobilvasarlas/mobiltarca ) - is there anything else?

Comment: Odd, the article I read that led me to it said it had been made available to all carriers. And at the bottom, the founders are listed as T-Mobile, Vodafone, and Telenor, along with some banks. Unfortunately I don't have anything more than that. Without an app and a back end to it, there's no way for you to use the NFC functions for payments. :(

Comment: Ok, thanks - I may contact them, about a carrier free app.