# Can I use my phone as a MIFARE Classic card?

Tags: nfc

I use a MIFARE Classic badge to access my building (the system is a French one: VIGIK).

I cloned a few tags already (tag to tag) and was wondering **if my Galaxy S22+ with Android 13 could act as a tag**, replacing the physical one? (I would like to possibly extend the answer to "any phone that supports NFC" if this is possible)

I read all kinds of things about this (notably Host-based Card Emulation, but also this [answer from 2012](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/35841/how-to-clone-an-nfc-tag-e-g-mifare-classic-to-an-android-device)) but in none of the discussions I saw a concrete answer to the question above for 2023 phones and Android version.

Comment: A similar topic: https://www.reddit.com/r/NFC/comments/vo5hnj/how_to_emulate_a_nxp_mifare_classic_1k_card_on/

Comment: There's [an answer posted in 2019](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/218956/44325) mentioning the impossibility of emulating/modifying sector 0, which is the UID (identifier). Otherwise, both the Reddit thread and an answer to the linked question mentioned that rooting is needed to touch the UID.